# How to call functions from data structure?

Tags: c#

I would like to be able to describe some actions as function calls represented in a datastructure. Then I would like to be able to loop through the data structure and call the functions.

This pseudo-code describes what I would like to achieve:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Action[] actions = new Action[]
    {
        new Action(DoAction1(5)),
        new Action(DoAction1(7)),
        new Action(DoAction2("100201")),
    };

    foreach (Action action in actions)
    {
        action.<Run the action function>;
    }
}

public static void DoAction1(int x)
{
}

public static void DoAction2(string x)
{
}
```

It kind of looks like delegates, but not quite.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: like.... `action()` in your foreach ?

Comment: I don't understand what you meant. The result should be executing DoAction1(5), then DoAction1(7) and DoAction2("100201"). But, it should not be hard coded. I want it represented in a data structure.

Comment: I don't understand what "representing it in a data structure" looks like to you; you put them in an array; which is a data structure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you're looking for?

```
Action[] actions = new Action[]
{
    new Action(()=>DoAction1(5)),
    new Action(()=>DoAction1(7)),
    new Action(()=>DoAction2("100201"))
};

foreach (Action action in actions)
{
    action();
}
```

Comment: Looks promising. How would the Action class look like to support this?

Comment: Sorry for my confusion. I didn't realize that the Action class was defined in .NET. I just picked that class name out of the blue. I deleted my own declaration of the Action class and it worked perfectly!

Comment: The only thing I would have wanted in addition is the ability to cleanly serialize this to JSON and back, but that doesn't seem to be possible.

Answer (score 0):

The Action class in .net allows you to directly assign lambdas

```
var actions = new List<Action>
{
    () => DoAction1(5),
    () => DoAction1(7),
    () => DoAction2("100201"),
};
```

then executing an array of actions can be done like :-

```
actions.ForEach(a => a());
```

then you can add more actions to the list

```
actions.Add(() => DoAction2("blah blah"));
```

Answer (score -1):

may be you can use reflection

```
var methodNames = typeof(MyType).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public |
                                            BindingFlags.Static)
                                .Select(x => x.Name)
                                .Distinct()
                                .OrderBy(x => x);
```

## OR

```
foreach (var property in yourObject.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    if (property.PropertyType.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IEnumerable)))
    {
        foreach (var item in (IEnumerable)property.GetValue(yourObject, null))
        {
             //do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like this is just inspecting some .NET object as data in order to manipulate that data. It does not look like I can call a function defined as data.

Answer (score -1):

Since you seem not to want to use the Action class, you can check out the [SharpByte](http://sharpbyte.net/) codebase, specifically the SharpByte.Dynamic namespace. It allows evaluating statements and executing scripts with just a single method call, like this:

```
someContextObject.Execute("[executable code here]");
```

However, you can use it another way which may be what you're looking for. When you execute one of those dynamic compilation/execution extension methods, [here's what's actually happening](https://bitbucket.org/jeff_varszegi/sharpbyte-net-public/src/f6bc1e2fc59993ae76e3afc248bee364ba189809/SharpByte.Core/Dynamic/ObjectExtensions.cs?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#ObjectExtensions.cs-396) (paraphrased):

```
IExecutable executable = ExecutableFactory.Default.GetExecutable(ExecutableType.Script, "[source code here]", optionalListOfParameterNames, optionalListOfNamespaces);
```

If you wanted to evaluate an expression/function instead of run multiple-lined statements, you'd use ExecutableType.Expression . The main point is that you can keep a reference around to an [IExecutable](https://bitbucket.org/jeff_varszegi/sharpbyte-net-public/src/f6bc1e2fc59993ae76e3afc248bee364ba189809/SharpByte.Core/Dynamic/IExecutable.cs?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default) object and run it as many times as you like, passing different parameter values each time. You can also copy IExecutable objects freely using the .Copy() method of each; they are designed to be thread-safe but lightweight, and references or copies could thus be placed in a data structure for further (re)use. [This post](https://digitalrumpus.wordpress.com/2017/08/14/easily-execute-dynamic-c-using-extension-methods/) explains a bit more.